# codeigniter view strange passing data to a function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

im a big problem with codeigniter php... i need to pass a value to a function in the same page of the view...

**the code of the view:**

```
echo '<div class="styled-select"> ';
echo '<fieldset>Select';
echo form_open('site/check_out');
echo form_dropdown('select', $options);
echo '</fieldset>';
echo form_submit('submit','Check-Out !');
echo '<div/>';
```

**the code of the controller:**

```
function check_out($select) {

            }
```

I need to pass the value of the form_dropdown to the function check_out like parameters of the function check_out($select);

i'm a newbie sorry for the error

any suggest ?
thanks averybody

Answer (score 2):

do it like this

```
echo '<div class="styled-select"> ';
echo '<fieldset>Select';
echo form_open('site/check_out');
echo form_dropdown('myOptions', $options);
echo '</fieldset>';
echo form_submit('submit','Check-Out !');
echo '<div/>';
```

When you submit the form

in `check_out` function of the `site` controller, do

```
print_r($_POST['myOptions'])
```

Comment: sorry but maybe I dont explain very well the problem...
in the controller the situation is like that:

function check_out($select){
...
}

i need the value of the form_dropdown in the paramater of the function

Comment: no it doesn't work like that. full form will  be posted to `check_out` function

Comment: do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: my friend you have to parse the $_Post to get the dropdown value selected.

Comment: can you help me with the code to parse the $_Post ?

Comment: I already had. when you press submit button on you form, this echo `$_POST['myOptions']` will print the value selected in the dropdown

Comment: yes I know but i need to pass this value like parameters of the function.
the function check_out have one parameter

function check_out($select) {

            }

Comment: dont do this `check_out($select) { }` , do `check_out() { echo $_POST['myOptions']; }`

Comment: impossibile i need the parametres...i cant modify check_out($select) to check_out() because other function use this...
sorry im no problem to echo and post a value ;)

Comment: then do `echo form_open('site/check_out/0');`

Comment: what to rewrite ? its all there. `echo '<div class="styled-select"> ';
echo '<fieldset>Select';
echo form_open('site/check_out/0');
echo form_dropdown('myOptions', $options);
echo '</fieldset>';
echo form_submit('submit','Check-Out !');
echo '<div/>';  `

Comment: it doesent work because " 0 " isnt the value posted in form_dropdown

Comment: what is the expected value ?

Comment: its dynamic ! should be 1 or should be 3 or 100 
its possible do this ?

Comment: From what you have posted, no